# Very Specific (Non-Gaming) Quad Monitor Setup Recommendations

Tags: monitors, multiple-monitors

I'm considering updating my monitor setup to a quad display workstation sometime soon, but I'm having trouble finding a monitor that fits my list of requirements...prepare yourself (in no particular order):

- 22"-24" (not against bigger...)
- 16:9 (or wider)
- 1080p (don't want 4K, it's just too expensive!)
- Rotating stand (I want the screens to be able to be either portrait or landscape)
- VGA, HDMI, DVI (though I guess I could skimp on one of them, most likely VGA)
- thin black/no bezel (again, would be really great, but if it's not possible it's not possible...)
- No speakers
- Non gaming
- Wide viewing angles

These monitors will be used solely as a productivity boost. No gaming at all, so I don't need any gaming related monitor features. They will be used for some graphics work, but nothing serious so maximum colour quality isn't a must, just something "decent".

I'm not too bothered about them having mounting plate points, but I suppose it would be a nice bonus. If they did have them I would probably put together a DIY stand at some point, but for now I definitely want them to all stand and rotate independently.

After all that, I'm not really sure where to cap the cost. The lower the cost the better. I'll judge how realistic this ideal setup is when I know how much it would cost me!

Any suggestions? I'm in the UK, so I'd prefer local options to having to order stuff from abroad. (Bonus points if you can supply a purchase link/cost.)

Comment: how thin is thin?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Pretty ambiguous I know... I guess it's just a case of the thinner the better! I don't have a hard limit on that requirement, and I suppose it's one of the ones I'm more flexible on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the few places where you can't go wrong with dell is their monitors. I don't own this *specific* model, but I can attest to them having excellent build quality

The [Dell 2417H](http://www1.euro.dell.com/content/products/productdetails.aspx/dell-u2417h-monitor?c=uk&cs=ukdhs1&l=en&s=dhs) is probably what you should be looking at, no pun intended. Dell lists them at GBP 245 on their website (with a discount), but you probably can comparison shop.

These are *really* small bezels, IPS (and which ensures awesome viewing angles and great colour quality). They're 1080p.

[image]

It does HDMI and DP only (but there's simple converters for DVI, or even VGA should the need arise).

Dell probably makes the best monitor stands on the market. They sell a dual monitor stand if that's what floats your boat. The standard stands give you height, tilt, *and* rotation adjustments, though this seems a new design. If you want to vesa mount them, they're compatible with the 100mm standard.

I'm not bothering to list out which requirements of yours they meet, cause they meet *all* of them. Right down to the lack of speakers. These are probably the monitors you want

Comment: If you're willing to spend more for higher resolution (1440p), I'm using a Dell U2515H and loving it. It's pretty much a U2415H w/ 1440p and a 25" panel.

Comment: heh, I got the model wrong - so I've updated. *many* of the benefits of the model I suggested are across the range, though I believe those ridiculously thin bezels are a new thing.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation! It ended up being a really close call between the HP Z23n @BigElittles lead me to and the Dell, but I was able to find the U2417H at the good price of £161.54, which tipped the scales in it's favour against the Z23n which I was £163.20 at it's best deal! An extra inch or so of screen space, USB3 and so many more input options really made it worth it. I _really_ like the look of those dual stands too, but maybe that will be a purchase for another day....

Answer (score 1):

Look at the HP elite display models. I have 3 of them, they all go from portrait/landscape with a spin of the hand and I love them for work. The bezels are a little under an inch wide, but if you overlap the screens its acceptable.

I have two different models, they are great for productivity. I usually have them in a sideways T configuration, but if I really want to get the most screen real estate nothing beats the H.

Comment: Thanks very much! In the end it was a really close choice between the HP Z23n you lead me to (which seem like a newer version of the Elite series with thin bezels etc), and the Dells @JourneymanGeek recommended, but the Dells narrowly won out!